# how to get table name with table using mysql in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, sequelize.js

hi i am getting some table as a output from storedprocedure in nodejs, but output only contains all table value as a json of array the table name as a key value is missing, does it return like that or there is something i am missing:

code

```
const GetData = (lt, ct, dd) => {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    qName =
      'CALL sp.procGetA("' +
      lT +
      '","' +
      cT +
      '",' +
      dd +
      ")";
    console.log(qName);
    var rest;
    db.query(qName, function (error, results) {
      if (error) return reject(er);
      return resolve(results);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Depends on how this stored procedure `sp.procGetA` is defined in MySQL.